# Getting table creation time in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

How do you get the creation time for a table in the dataset?

bq show my_project:my_dataset.my_table

gives you

```
Table my_project:my_dataset.my_table

   Last modified         Schema        Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration  
 ----------------- ------------------ ------------ ------------- ------------ 
  **16 Oct 14:47:41**   |- field1: string   3            69                        
                    |- field2: string                                          
                    |- field3: string
```

We can use the "Last Modified" date but its missing the year!. Also there needs to be a cryptic log applied to parse the date out.

Is this meta information available through any other specific 'bq' based commands?

I am looking to use this information to determine a appropriate table decorator that can be  used on the table since it seems like if the decorator is going back 4 hours (on recurring basis) and the table/partition has existed for only 3hrs the query errors out.

Ideally it would be nice if the decorator usage defaults the time window to "now - table creation time"  if the specified window was larger than "now-table creation time".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use bq --format=json you can get the information easily:

```
$ bq --format=prettyjson show publicdata:samples.wikipedia
{
  "creationTime": "1335916132870", ...
}
```

This is the exact value to use in the table decorator.

While I'm not sure that I like the idea of having a 'really low start value' be interpreted as table creation time, I've got other options:

1. `Table@0` means table at creation time
2. `Table@0` means table at the earliest time at which a snapshot is available.

I'm leaning towards #2, since snapshots can only go back 7 days in time.

Comment: Nice. The format option might do the trick. Can you please elaborate on the "I'm leaning towards #2, since snapshots can only go back 7 days in time." both option #1 and #2 seem same (Table@0) ? (Am I missing something)

Comment: Regarding your question since snapshot history is only available for 7 days, if the table is older than 7 days, the earliest snapshot that is available might be later than the table creation time.

Comment: FYI the change to do #2 has been checked in and should hopefully go live next week.

Comment: This is not satisfying because the CLI command does not return only this information.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW this information is available in the API, which the bq tool calls under the covers: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource

Answer (score 0):

The [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables) view contains the creation time for all tables in a dataset.

For your example,

```
SELECT
  table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, creation_time
FROM
  `my_project`.my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE
  table_name = 'my_table'
```