# How can I get a BigQuery table's meta data (record counts or last update date or creation date) via BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to write a BigQuery command line command that will retrieve the last modification time of a BigQuery table. How can I do that?

I will use the BigQuery table only if its last modified datetime is greater than some datetime.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple query that shows metadata about all the tables in your dataset:

```
SELECT * FROM <dataset>.__TABLES__;
```

You can add

```
WHERE table_id='<table_name>'
```

if you want to restrict it to a certain table.

These are the columns returned:

```
project_id, dataset_id, table_id, creation_time, last_modified_time, row_count, size_bytes, type
```

The web UI says this query processes 0 bytes, so I think it's free to run.

Comment: Do you have any idea if this can be extended to the project level? I guess I could `UNION` a bunch of statements, but if there's a way, I could say something like `select * from <project-id>.__DATASETS__.__TABLES__` or something similar, please do let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @CodingInCircles I haven't seen a way to get metadata for a whole project. We've written some tooling to loop through each dataset and combine data. A UNION would work too, but you'd likely need to manually update it every time you added a dataset.

Comment: Yeah. We'd have to do something similar too. Sucks that there isn't anything to go through an entire project's worth of datasets.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following command line to show a table's metadata :

```
bq show project_id:dataset_id.table_id
```

You will get a result like below. Use `grep` to obtain the date if you want to automate the process.

```
  Last modified           Schema           Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration
 ----------------- ----------------------- ------------ ------------- ------------
  24 Apr 16:29:28   |- state: string        5365794      165658304
                    |- gender: string
                    |- year: integer
                    |- name: string
                    |- occurence: integer
```

Comment: Please be aware that these details are cached, and they are not up to date every time.

Comment: @Pentium10 AFAIK it's always updated - any experience where it was not?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Yes, we have several tables where these are off, for example here Total Rows, Bytes are not reported `bq show aerobic-forge-504:wr_live.cart_event`

Comment: How can we do this with Java API?

Comment: @foxwendy check out the documentation, section "Managing tables". They have java examples : https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables

Comment: You can get the result in json format, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412751/getting-table-creation-time-in-big-query#answer-19414513), so there's no need to grep.